# How to dive into the PostgreSQL's optimizer and trace each step it takes to optimize the query?

Tags: postgresql

Just like the MEMO structure in SQL Server which is kind of a "paper trail" of steps the optimizer takes in optimizing the query. Does PostgreSQL have the similar structure which records steps the optimizer takes?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no detailed optimizer audit/reporting structure or function.

Your best tool is 'gdb'. Unlike MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL is open source; you can just build with debug symbols enabled, attach a debugger, and trace exactly what it's doing.

That doesn't mean it's easy, of course. A canned set of breakpoints and gdb macros to produce a trace of what the planner/optimiser are doing would be very nice. I'm not aware of any such tool at this point.

`gdb`'s tracepoints, or `perf` userspace tracepoints, will be very useful to you.

You can also enable detailed debug logging and some of the trace parameters in `postgresql.conf` then examine the resulting detailed log files.

There's some documentation (which I've added info on dumping plan trees, etc, to) in the PostgreSQL developer FAQ: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ . This may be useful. You should also read the main developer docs.